# Sending from Java to PHP Scripting

Tags: java, php

first time question. Anyways, I have a bit of a project, basically it has me writing up a GUI using Netbean's GUI builder to get information from a customer and then sending that information into a PHP script. I know that I can get the string from jTextField1.gettext(); and thats well and all, but the problem comes with sending that specific information to the PHP script that will send it to the mySQL database in the group's website.

Java coding for a method that should theoretically work when it's called in the submit action method:

```
public void Dsend() throws Exception {
URL hp = new URL("http://www.luxuryparking.comeze.com/DBinput.php"); 
HttpURLConnection hpCon = (HttpURLConnection) hp.openConnection();
hpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
hpCon.setDoOutput(true);
hpCon.setDoInput(true);

        // important: get output stream before input stream
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(hpCon.getOutputStream());
ps.print(jTextField7.getText());
     ps.print("secondKey=secondValue;");

// we have to get the input stream in order to actually send the request
hpCon.getInputStream();

// close the print stream
ps.close();   
}
```

PHP Script:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=a4335408_data1", $username, $password);

foreach ($_POST as $key =&gt; $value) {
switch ($key) {
    case 'license':
        $license = $value;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}

$license='1234567';

$sql = "INSERT INTO Reservation (LicensePlate) VALUES (:license)";

$q = $conn->prepare($sql);

$q->execute(array(':license'=>$license));
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$q->execute(array(':license'=>$license));
```

should be

```
$q->execute(array('license'=>$license));
```

On the Java side `doInput(false)` without getInputStream seems more appropiate. Apache's HttpClient might be a more helpful API.

Comment: Where would I get some info on that API? and would that work on 000webhost?

Comment: [HttpClient](http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheHttpClient/article.html) is simply an old library around java.net.URLConnection. The link is a nice overview. The API is not a great improvement, but a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

In the java procedure, data sent to server should be formatted in "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

See also: [How to use HttpURLConnection POST data to web server?](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139)

Comment: I'm having problems trying to understand on how to get each jtextfield as it's own variable on PHP, as I have to get other information such as the email, phone number, etc.

Comment: On the java side: ps.print("email=" + URLEncoder.encode(jTextFieldEmail.getText(), "UTF-8")); On the php side: $_POST['email']

Comment: Huh. Seems quite simple to just have that XD;

Comment: Might as well ask, what would be the proper way to call the method under the button?